# How to animate tab title colors in Android view pagers?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablelayout

I am trying to do something like flipboard app, where the tab title colors follows the swipe.

The following screenshot is taken from FlipBoard app, it describes what I want to achieve, as you can see the red color on the tab titles, follows the swipe.

How I can achieve this?

[image: Flipboard screenshit]

Comment: there is no such inbuild method

Comment: Yeah i know, but any ideia how to control this animation?

Comment: you need to do custom for it